# Android : Restrict app not to run on Tablet

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-screen-support, android-screen, android-permissions

I developed an application. And now i want that my application should run only on mobiles not on tablets. I searched for that and tried as:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false" 
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="false" />
```

I write this in androidmenifest.xml file. But it is of no use. My application is running on tablet now also.

Am i declared is wrong, or i should include anything else.

Please suggest what should i do to restrict my application from running on tablet.

Comment: it wont restrict your app from running but from showing the app in google play for such devices

Comment: keep your layout files in layout-swxxxdp or in layout-hxdpi etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want it to only run on non-tablets?  Is there a feature (like SMS) you need?  If so, add a uses-feature tag in your manifest.  If its based on screen size, why not just scale up and get more users?

Also, screen size means nothing for phone vs tablet.  My phone is a Note 2, it has more pixels than original generation tablets.  You could disable all the devices you don't want on the play store, but it would be a pain.

Comment: Yes i am having the sms functionality. And also it is the requirement of app not to run on Tab. Thank you for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Try adding a uses-feature for the feature android.hardware.telephony.  THat will only install you if it has a cellular radio.  Beyond that, there is no way to do this programaticly and you cannot depend on dpi or screen size-  larger phones and smaller tablets will break any attempt to do that.  I'd talk to your client-  most likely they don't want it to not appear on tablets because they're tablets, they want it not to appear if the device can't do SMS because then the app wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to do this is use:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />
```

This way you assure the device doesn't have phone support, what is the case on all the tablets I know.

Answer (score 2):

support screens won't restrict an application downloaded from google play, If you want to restrict, just use compatible screens

```
<compatible-screens>
<screen android:screenSize=["small" | "normal" | "large" | "xlarge"]
        android:screenDensity=["ldpi" | "mdpi" | "hdpi" | "xhdpi"] />
...
</compatible-screens>
```

read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)

Answer (score 1):

Support Screen will effect after you will upload your apk file to Google playstore, untill you will not get this feature affected.

Also see the [Filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) document for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5707822/2190341) on how to check for SMS (or telephony) functionality. Of course, the most appropriate solution is to filter on Google Play. But if you miss something and want to check during run time, I think this would help.