# Check if a phone can send SMS

Tags: java, android

I've already read some related question about it but most of them were targeting calls, not SMS. What I've found so far is:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (manager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE) {
    // I guess here are devices that are unable to send SMS
} else {
    // can send SMS
}
```

Is this true, devices with TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE are unable to send SMS?
I don't really understand the description of TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE, which is "No phone radio."

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814258/what-is-the-procedure-to-detect-if-an-android-device-has-sms-send-capability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes with **TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE** you can't send SMS.As radio network is required to send SMS. However you can use some IP based messengers like whats app, ebuddy on them

if you see **[android.hardware.telephony](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)** (which you specify using **uses-feature** tag in Android manifest file), you will notice send/read/write SMS are mentioned under this feature.

**[Galaxy TAB example,Can't make calls still phone type comes as PHONE_TYPE_CDMA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196833/android-device-phone-call-ability)**, so adding additional check for **line number** will be required for such cases, as shown in above link

Comment: Do not test line number, it is forbidden by some network operators. My phone with Vodafone network has empty line number, and it can send SMS. Try to make SMS Intent and find, if there are applications to handle it installed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
Boolean canSendSMS (Context context)
{
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
return (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY) || pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY_CDMA))
}
```