# How can I check if a device supports SMS?

Tags: android, sms

I want to disable SMS features programmatically on tablets without SIM card slot.

I have tried this:

```
if (context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) != null)
{
    // SMS features: enable
}
else
{
    // SMS features: disable
}
```

but on my NVidia Shield Tablet K1 (without sim card slot) `context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)` returns something and it looks like I have telephony service.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: There's no promise that getSystemService will return null if a given feature isn't available.  I'm not sure why you assumed it would, there's nothing in the documentation that says it will.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a phone can send SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924099/check-if-a-phone-can-send-sms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not assume that `getSystemService()` to retrieve the `TelephonyManager` would necessarily return `null` in this case.

The official way to check for telephony is to call `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)` on a `PackageManager`, which you can get by calling `getPackageManager()`.

I have dusted off my NVIDIA Shield K1, and I get `false` from `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)` on that device.